# How to visualize dimensions of frame components in beamer?

Tags: beamer, dimensions

Is there a package to visualize dimension of all frame components (head/footline, sidebars, navigation bar etc) in `beamer`? I tried to search for something similar to `layout` package, but did not succeed.

Comment: @Jubobs, unfortunately it does not give answer about frame components, only about layout in general.

Comment: @zeliboba: What would you expect if not the general layout? The "dimension of all frame components" is the "layout in general" or how would you distinguish between these two?

Comment: @strpeter by "dimension of all frame components" I mean sidebars, navigation bar etc, by "layout in general" normal latex layout as in the link above. Difference is simple: there is no sidebars in the latex layout, they are introduced by `beamer`.